# What Is the Correct Way To Use AbstractReactiveWebInitializer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I've got a Spring WebFlux application running successfully as a standalone spring boot application.

I am attempting to run the same application in a Tomcat container, and following the documentation, I've created a class that extends `AbstractReactiveWebInitializer`. The class requires that I implement a method `getConfigClasses` that would return classes normally annotated with `@Configuration`. If the working spring boot app started with a class called `ApplicationInitializer`, then the resulting implementations would look like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "my.pkg")
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableCaching
public class ApplicationInitializer {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationInitializer.class, args);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ServletInitializer extends AbstractReactiveWebInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {ApplicationInitializer.class};
    }
}
```

When deployed, the only thing that starts is `ApplicationInitializer`, none of the autoconfigured Spring Boot classes (Cloud Config, DataSource, etc) ever kick off.

The [documenation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-httphandler) states this is the class I need to implement, I just expected the remainder of the spring environment to "just work".

---

How should I be using this class to deploy a Reactive WebFlux Spring Boot application to a Tomcat container ?

---

Edit:

After some additional research, I've narrowed it down to likely just Cloud Config. During bean post processing on startup, the `ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor` should be enriched with additional property sources (from cloud config), but it appears to be the default Spring properties instead, with no additional sources.

The misisng properties is causing downstream beans to fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Spring Boot does not support WAR packaging for Spring WebFlux applications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file).

The documentation you're referring to is the Spring Framework doc; Spring Framework does support that use case, but without Spring Boot.

Comment: Can't understand this answer....if the spring frameworks supports it then, in turn, wouldn't spring boot support it too? What would I miss if I just extend it?

Comment: Spring Boot cannot support all possible features of Spring Framework. For example, JSPs aren’t supported with executable JARs (this limitation is outlined in the docs). In this case, the default server for WebFlux applications in Spring Boot is Reactor Netty - this server is not a Servlet container and does not support WAR deployments natively. The Spring Boot team thought that the amount of work required to support this use case (and many other related features) was not worth it.

Comment: Ok but I tried to deploy a .war on my weblogic and it worked...I made the main class extend AbstractServerInitializer and voila. I don't know what it's doing under the hood though...maybe it's using netty anyway?

Answer (score 0):

you can extend SpringBootServletInitializer, add add reactive servlet on onStartup method